# Collapsable divs in forms

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I want to create collapsable divs inside my forms in Ruby on Rails because I have a very long list of form items to edit or create.

Is it possible to do that without breaking MVC rules?

Thanks

**Maybe:**

Use different fieldsets as collapsable divs

Comment: have you checked http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms you might divide your form into a few parts

Comment: I think is better to have everything in one form.. and use different fieldsets as collapsable divs.

Comment: structuring your form has nothing to do with MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're looking for something like jQuery toggle function.

See here: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: toggle is perfectly fine used alone. Just add `display:none` to the div you want to hide first (and which would appear once clicked). Personaly, I hate accordions